# (JPQL) Retrieve all entities which are not in @OneToMany property

Tags: java, jpa, jpql

How can I get all ***Verses*** which are not in ***Receivers*** ***usedVersed*** property ?

Tried something like

```
@NamedQuery(name="unusedVersesByReceiver", query="SELECT v.id FROM Verse v WHERE v.id 
NOT IN (SELECT r.usedVerses FROM Receiver r WHERE r = :_receiver)"
```

But I get:

```
The state field path 'r.usedVerses' cannot be resolved to a collection typ
```

Here my classes:

```
class Verse{
private Long Id;
private String SomeText;
...
}
class Receiver{
private Long Id;
@OneToMany
private List<Verse> usedVerses;
...
}
```

UPDATE: I altered my entity classes to:

```
class Verse{
private Long Id;
private String SomeText;
@OneToMany
private User usedBy;
...
}


class Receiver{
private Long Id;
...
}
```

and tried this JPQL

```
@NamedQuery(name = "testUnusedVerses", query= "SELECT v.id FROM Verse v WHERE v.usedBy 
!= :_receiver")
```

Get no error, but also not a correct solution. No user is retrieved.

Answer (score 0):

Try with just `v`, not `v.id` and use `NOT MEMBER OF` instead of `NOT IN`

```
SELECT v.id FROM Verse v, Receiver r
    WHERE v NOT MEMBER OF r.usedVerses 
    AND r = :_receiver
```

Comment: The failure still consists. 
Also simpler `@NamedQuery(name = "testUnusedVerses", query= "SELECT r.usedVerses FROM Receiver r WHERE r = :_receiver")` code returns same error.

Comment: How try with `"SELECT r.usedVerses vs FROM Receiver r WHERE r = :_receiver`

Comment: Isn't the name after `r.usedVerses`  `vs` not just the identifier ? Error still exists.

Comment: @der_wolle Updated the answer and let me know if error still exists.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot select an attribute that represents a collection, which is the case with usedVerses, you have to join on your collection attribute and assign it an alias which will refer to an item from that collection, then you can select that alias. 
In your case it would be:
select uv from Receiver r join r.usedVerses uv where r = :_receiver

Comment: Thats works, but as I have written I need all Verses which are **not** in the usedVersed List.